# MVC3 Model with collection creating new collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I have a model that contains a collection property as List().  In my view, each of the ChildModel objects is rendered in a table row via it's own Editor Template.

On postback, my model gets bound correcty in that contains a list of ChildModels with the correct about of items originally created in the view, but all the properties of the ChildModel are null, with the exception of the single Editable field.

Based upon this, it appears as if it is creating an entirely new collection of objects, and forgetting all about any values set previously.

I've tried adding the other child object properties to hidden fields, but I still get default values (nulls or zeros) for all properties accept for the one I have created an edit control for. (textbox).

Any thoughts on how to get at a minimum a key field for my item so I can simply update my existing collection?

I found that my hidden field value is in the Request.Form on postback with the Quantity values as well as the values I put in the Hidden fields.  I'm not sure why the FormValueProvider isn't parsing those values.

Comment: Are you sure your hidden model properties are being populated in your view correctly?

Comment: Yeah, they're there but the seem to get lost during binding.